# Slim framework: match routes starting with certain string

Tags: slim

Using Slim framework V2.6.3, is it possible to define a single route which captures all **routes starting with certain string**?

For example, I'd like to capture routes starting with **apple-touch-icon**, like these:

- https://www.example.com/apple-touch-icon.png
- https://www.example.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
- https://www.example.com/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Slim 2, you can define route conditions:

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v2/routing/conditions.html